# Place node not at center but near edge of a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, circles

Consider this example, which required some manual tinkering for the nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

    % Axes
    \def\xmin{-4}\def\xmax{4}
    \def\ymin{-3}\def\ymax{3}
    \draw[->] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax+0.2,0) node[right] {$q_1$};
    \draw[->] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node[above] {$q_2$};

    % Shell
    \draw[blue] (0,0) circle [x radius=\xmax-1, y radius=\ymax-1] node[below right=35] {$E$};
    \draw[red] (0,0) circle [x radius=\xmax-0.5, y radius=\ymax-0.5] node[below right=55] {$E + \Delta E$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a smart way to place nodes just inside/outside of circles in `TikZ` so that they automatically reposition in case I decide to change the size of the circles later on? To silence any pedantic complains, "smart" here means as short, readable and flexible a syntax as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I illustrate two options below. The first one requires the most changes, as it uses `\node`s to draw the ellipses, and uses a `label` to add the, ehm, labels.

The second uses polar coordinates to specify the position of the nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

    % Axes
    \def\xmin{-4}\def\xmax{4}
    \def\ymin{-3}\def\ymax{3}
    \draw[->] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax+0.2,0) node[right] {$q_1$};
    \draw[->] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node[above] {$q_2$};

    % Shell
    \node[
      blue,
      draw,
      ellipse,
      inner sep=0pt, % not strictly necessary when the nodes are this large
      minimum width=(\xmax-1)*2cm,
      minimum height=(\ymax-1)*2cm,
      label={[above left,blue]330:$E$}] {};
    \node[
      red,
      draw,
      ellipse,
      inner sep=0pt, % not strictly necessary when the nodes are this large
      minimum width=(\xmax-0.5)*2cm,
      minimum height=(\ymax-0.5)*2cm,
      label={[below right,red]330:$E+\Delta E$}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

    % Axes
    \def\xmin{-4}\def\xmax{4}
    \def\ymin{-3}\def\ymax{3}
    \draw[->] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax+0.2,0) node[right] {$q_1$};
    \draw[->] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node[above] {$q_2$};

    % Shell
    \draw[blue] (0,0) circle [x radius=\xmax-1, y radius=\ymax-1];
    \node[above left,blue] at (315:\xmax-1 and \ymax-1) {$E$};
    \draw[red] (0,0) circle [x radius=\xmax-0.5, y radius=\ymax-0.5];
    \node[below right,red] at (315:\xmax-0.5 and \ymax-0.5) {$E + \Delta E$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 But I would've used the `label` option of the node to place the text. Cleaner code and no need to name the ellipses. `:)`

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli Yeah, perhaps more appropriate, I'll edit later.